Why are there several rounds during a conclave?
I was told by some Catholic friends that the act of choosing the Pope during the conclave is not a "human" choice but rather the choice is infused by the Holy Spirit.
In other words, the cardinals are just vessels for a heavenly choice.
If this is correct, why are there several rounds of votes then?

The linked answer is not really an answer to my question - my concern was with the fact that the Holy Spirit is supposed to provide the answer, but nevertheless, it takes several rounds to make the choice. I get that the answer is that people are fillable and possibly do not understand the message correctly.
